# How to check controller attribute from AuthorizationFilterContext in IAuthorizationFilter OnAuthorization method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the current .NET 6/8 I implement custom authorization filter which use dependency injection, `IConfiguration` in this case. The custom authorization should be executed when the controller is marked by my custom attribute. How to get this info from `AuthorizationFilterContext` in `OnAuthorization` method?

```cs
[MyMarkerAttribute]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
}

public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public MyAuthorizationFilter(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // how to check the called controller is marked by MyMarkerAttribute?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
   private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

   public CustomAuthorizationFilter(IConfiguration configuration)=>_configuration = configuration;

   public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
    
      var someConfigValue = _configuration["SomeConfigKey"];

      // Accessing information about the controller
      var controllerInfo = context.ActionDescriptor?.DisplayName;

      // Accessing attributes on the controller
      var controllerAttributes = 
      context.ActionDescriptor?.EndpointMetadata
      .OfType<CustomAuthorizeAttribute>();

     // Example: Check if the controller has a specific attribute
     if (controllerAttributes?.Any() == true)
      {
        // Your authorization logic 
      }
   }
}

// Register your custom authorization filter in Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationFilter>();
}
```

Comment: Yes, `context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<MyMarkerAttribute>().Any()` works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an interface to detect your marker attributes, I think this would work:

```cs
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var filters = context.Filters;

    if (filters.OfType<IMyMarkerAttribute>().Any())
    {
        // your code to handle MyMarkerAttribute
    }

    // rest of the code
}
```

I didn't test that without a marker interface but should work with class as well.

Comment: Using `context.Filters` requires the attribute is marked by `IFilterMetadata`, i.e. `class MyMarkerAttribute: Attribute, IFilterMetadata`.